# Make dataframe from a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I would like to make a dataframe from a list of n. Each list contains 3 different list inside. I am only intrested in 1 list of those 3 list inside. The list I am intrested in is a data.frame with 12 obs of 12 variables.

My imput tmp in my lapply function is a list of n with each 5 observations.
2 of those observations are the Latitude and Longitude. This is how my lapply function looks like:

```
DF_Google_Places<- lapply(tmp, function(tmp){

Latitude<-tmp$Latitude

Longitude<-tmp$Longitude

LatLon<- paste(Latitude,Longitude, sep=",")

res<-GET(paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=",LatLon,"&radius=200&types=food&key=AIzaSyDS6usHdhdoGIj0ILtXJKCjuj7FBmDEzpM", sep=""))

  jsonAnsw<-content(res,"text")

  myDataframe<- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(res,"text"))

})
```

My question is: how do I get this list of 12 obs of 12 variables into a dataframe from a list of n ?

Could anyone help me out?, Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: maybe using lapply() and Reduce(). Something along the lines of:
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), lapply(list_of_lists, function(x) x[[df_number]]) ))

Comment: I added some more text which contains my lapply function

Comment: Can you show another couple of examples of the objects you're working with, maybe `str(x)` where `x` is your object. Depending on the structure of it e.g. with `x <- list(a=list(b=1,c=2),d=list(b=3,c=4))` you might try something like this:  `y <- do.call(data.frame,
    list(sapply(names(x[[1]]), function(t) sapply(1:length(x),function(j) x[[j]][[t]]))))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting my comment as an answer so I can show output to show you the idea:

```
x <- list(a=list(b=1,c=2),d=list(b=3,c=4))
```

So `x` is a nested list structure, in this case with consistent naming / structure one level down.

```
> x
$a
$a$b
[1] 1

$a$c
[1] 2


$d
$d$b
[1] 3

$d$c
[1] 4
```

Now we'll use `do.call` to build the `data.frame`. We need to pass it a named list of arguments, so we'll use `list(sapply` to get the named list. We'll walk the higher level of the list by position, and the inner level by name since the names are consistent across sub-lists at the inner level. Note here that the key idea is essentially to reverse what would be the intuitive way of indexing; since I want to pull observations at the second level from across observations at the first level, the inner call to `sapply` traverses multiple values of level one for each value of the name at level two.

```
y <- do.call(data.frame, 
             list(sapply(names(x[[1]]), 
                         function(t) sapply(1:length(x),
                                            function(j) x[[j]][[t]]))))

> y
  b c
1 1 2
2 3 4
```

Try breaking apart the command to see what each step does. If there is any consistency in your sub-list structure, you should be able to adapt this approach to walk that structure in the right order and fold the data you need.

On a large dataset, this would not be efficient, but for 12x12 it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!